# Erro de compilação laço For

Tags: c, c++, loop, declaração-de-variável

Estou fazendo um programa que pergunta quantas notas o usuário irá digitar e, depois disso, entra em um laço 'for' perguntando quais são as notas para digitar. As notas ficam armazenadas em uma *array* e por fim, é calculada a média.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int qt, tot, med;
cout << "Quantidade de notas: ";
cin >> qt;

int nt[] = {};

for(i = 0; i <= qt; i++){
    cout << "Digite a nota " << i+1 << " : " << endl;
    cin >> nt[i];
    tot = tot + nt[i];
}

med = (tot / qt);

cout << "Media = " << med << endl;

return main();
}
```

O problema é que sempre que tento compilar, aparece o seguinte erro:

> ```
>  'i' was not declared in this scope
>   for(i = 0; i <= qt; i++){
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem vários erros no código, quando resolver este aparecerá outros. Vamos arrumar pelo menos uma parte:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Quantidade de notas: ";
    int qt;
    cin >> qt;
    int nt[qt] = {}; //isto é mais C que C++
    int tot = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < qt; i++) {
        cout << "Digite a nota " << i + 1 << " : " << endl;
        cin >> nt[i];
        tot += nt[i];
    }
    cout << "Media = " << tot / qt << endl;
}
```

[Veja funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iO3nGV). E [no **Coding Ground**](http://tpcg.io/NZgSwW). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/VariableDeclaration.cpp).

O *array* não tinha tamanho e iria corromper a memória.

A variável de iteração do `for` não estava declarada, conforme o compilador informava.

O contador ia até uma posição depois do tamanho entrado.

Não pode chamar a mesma função sem uma condição de saída e que ela não seja muito longa para não dar *stackoverflow*.

Pode ser que queira médias com parte decimal, este código não permite isso.

O resto é mais cosmético.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá Nate, com relação ao refereido erro:

```
'i' was not declared in this scope
for(i = 0; i <= qt; i++){ ...}
```

O que faltou foi colocar mesmo o tipo da variável i, pois neste contexto tem de ser declarada como uma variável, e que será usada como controle do laço de repetição `for`. Ficando da seguinte maneira:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= qt; i++){ ...}
```

Achei engraçado o fato de que desenvolvi um código há alguns dias atrás para fazer a mesma operação, da mesma forma como você pensou. Calcular a média aritmética de uma certa quantidade de notas informadas pelo usuário.

Implementei minha solução utilizando classe, objetos, arrays dinâmicos e acho interessante deixar para você aqui, para estuda-lo e analisa-lo. Segue abaixo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Calculadora{

private:
    double resultado;
    int qtdNotas;
    double *nota = new double;
public:
    //Setters
    void setResultado(double resultado){
        this->resultado = resultado;
    }
    void setQtdNotas(int qtdNotas){
        this->qtdNotas = qtdNotas;
    }
    void setNota(double *nota){
        for(int i=0; i <= getQtdNotasArray(); i++){
            *(this->nota + i) = *(nota + i);
        }
    }
    //Getters
    double getResultado(){
        return this->resultado;
    }
    int getQtdNotasArray(){
        return this->qtdNotas - 1;
    }
    int getQtdNotas(){
        return this->qtdNotas;
    }

    //Média
    double calculaMedia(){
        double resultado = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int qtdNotas = this->getQtdNotas();

       while(i <= this->getQtdNotasArray()){
            resultado += *(this->nota + i);
            i++;
        }

        resultado = resultado / (double)qtdNotas;

        return this->resultado = resultado;
    }
};


int main()
{
    int qtdNotas; //Recebe quantidade de notas informadas pelo usuário, a média é baseada nessa quantidade
    double *nota = new double; //Declaração de variável ponteiro, utilizada para posterior criação do array dinâmico

    Calculadora *o = new Calculadora; //Cria o objeto "o" e utiliza e o utiliza para reservar espaço na memória

    cout << "Programa Media de um Aluno. Abaixo serao solicitadas as notas dos 4 bimentres para ser calculada a media final.\n";
    cout << "A media do aluno sera baseada em quantas notas? ";
    cin >> qtdNotas; cout << endl;

    o->setQtdNotas(qtdNotas); //Insere quantidade de notas sobre qual o calculo será feito

    for(int i=0; i <= o->getQtdNotasArray(); i++){
        cout << i + 1 << " : ";
        cin >> *(nota + i); cout << endl; //Guarda na variável ponteiro, em seu devido espaço(array), os valores das medias inseridas pelo usuário
    }

    o->setNota(nota); //pega referência do ponteiro onde foram alocadas as notas e passa pela função para ser atribuída a um atributo dentro da classe
    o->calculaMedia(); //com todos os dados já inseridos nos atributos do objeto, este método somente manda executar o calculo da média aritmética simples, e manda guardar o resultado em um atributo de nome resultado para somente ser recuperado posteriormente

    cout << "Notas recolhidas com sucesso! A media para este aluno e de: " << o->getResultado(); //Método que somente recupera o resultado dos calculos já realizados anteriormente

    return 0;
}
```

Estou rodando meus programas na IDE Code::Blocks, utilizando compilador gcc e padrão C++ 11 ISO. Fica aqui minha contribuição, aliás estou iniciando em C++ então qualquer erro grave de aspecto técnico fique a vontade para reportar.